# mod_rewrite to IIS URL Rewrite XML syntax

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have some trouble translating these rewrite rules to IIS URL Rewrite XML syntax.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-content/uploads/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/plugins/ack_auto_image_resize/ack_generate_image.php?uri=$1 [L]
```

Anyone got any ideas? =)

Answer (score 0):

IIS 7 will do the conversion for you.

1. Double-click on the URL Rewrite feature for the site
2. On the right choose "import rules"
3. Paste the rules into the "Rewrite Rules" block
4. Apply

I have used this method with several rewrite rule sets with no issues.